# Lodash: generate new array from existing array, using existing values

Tags: javascript, arrays, lodash

I have a array as below

```
[{
        "first_name": "Anna",
        "last_name": "William",
        "class": "math",
        "year": "1990"
    },
    {
        "first_name": "Tom",
        "last_name": "Cruise",
        "class": "biology",
        "year": "1991"
    }
]
```

I am trying to transform it to new array

```
[{
        "name": "Anna William",
        "class": "math"
    },
    {
        "name": "Tom Cruise",
        "class": "biology"
    }
]
```

My simple solution is obviously using loop to create a new array, but it's long and not elegant :P. Lodash help me a lot in making code short, and readable. Any suggestion to transform the array using Lodash's features, please share me.

Comment: You don't even need lodash for this, just use [`Array.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).

Comment: [You-Dont-Need-Lodash-Underscore](https://github.com/you-dont-need/You-Dont-Need-Lodash-Underscore#quick-links)

Comment: Thanks @adiga, I am learning and coding in project, your ref is so useful.

Comment: You can go through all the [Array.prototype methods](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/prototype#Methods). In most of the cases, you can achieve array manipulations using one or a combination of these methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can map it new array with desired values only using [**.map**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

```js
let arr = [{"first_name": "Anna","last_name": "William","class": "math","year": "1990"},{"first_name": "Tom","last_name": "Cruise","class": "biology","year": "1991"}]

let op = arr.map(e => ({name: `${e.first_name} ${ e.last_name}`, class:e.class }))

console.log(op)
```